# Can json have only key without value?

Tags: json

Json format defines keys and values. And how about the following

```
{
      "Kill"
}
```

Is it an acceptable json format?

Comment: No. [Here is the definition](https://www.json.org) of what is acceptable and what is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [original JSON introduction](https://json.org) is extremely straight-forward, including diagrams of the possible constructions. Among the text content is this:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with `{` left brace and ends with `}` right brace. Each name is followed by `:` colon and the name/value pairs are separated by `,` comma.

The later [ECMA-404 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/) includes similar wording:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs. A name is a string. A single colon token follows each name, separating the name from the value. A single
> comma token separates a value from a following name.

The [IETF standard, RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html#section-4) puts it this way:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets
> surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a
> string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name
> from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following
> name.  The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

In every case, note that *every* key is followed by a colon and a value. Since there is no colon following the key in your example, it is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

No, in [JSON notation](https://www.json.org/), an object is an unordered set of key/value pairs, and both the key and the value are required elements.

If the object you've shown is the **only** thing you want to have in your JSON text, you could just remove the object wrapper:

```json
"Kill"
```

That's perfectly valid JSON. (There was a time when JSON was defined as requiring the outermost element to be an object or an array, but that hasn't been true for many, many years.)